# pass string by reference when use JNA to access .dll

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, jna

I need to use JNA to call dll from Java.

the definition of the function in the header file of the dll that I need to invoke is like this:

```
bool DmgrGetVersion(char * szVersion);
```

So I need to redefine an interface in Java, and the function becomes:

```
boolean DmgrGetVersion(String szVersion);
```

But, I need pass string by reference, which means my pass-in string variable needs to recieve a new value from the argument of the function. How do I achieve this? (for example if I call DmgrGetVersion(ver) and szVersion in the function is assigned "1.0.1" at the end of the function, ver needs to be assigned "1.0.1" as well)

I heard many people said that `String[] str = new String[1]`, `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` can be used, but not for my case because I cannot change the content of the function since i do not have the source code of the dll. (all I have is the header file and .lib and .dll files)

BTW in the JNA documentation there's no type conversion for char*. (only char and const char* and char**)

So is it still possible for me to achieve my need? thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable object in Java. You can't change content of String object. `String[] str = new String[1]` is analog for `char**`

Comment: I know it is immutable but i have no other good options... and in the JNA documentation there's no type conversion for char*. (only char and const char* and char**)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an instance of `PointerByReference`, then use `PointerByReference.getValue()` to retrieve the "returned" pointer.  `Pointer.getString(0)` will then provide the referenced string.

While `String[]` may work, it leaves you with no way of referencing the "returned" pointer, should you need to free it.